# Scriptella Change delimiter of csv to tab

Tags: csv, scriptella, non-printing-characters

I am using Sciptella to parse a document and make a csv file. I want the delimiter in csv to be tab. Presently I'm able to change the delimiter to any other printable single character e.g. ;
as

`<connection id="out" driver="csv" url="hello.csv">
separator=;
</connection>`

Please help me find out how to give a non printable character as a csv file's separator
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was very simple just didnt know it may also work:

`<connection id="out" driver="csv" url="hello.csv"> separator=\t </connection>`

Comment: Thank you Sanghita. Just in case if anyone needs more details about escaping of special characters, please refer to [Properties class JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)).